# Alter fields in Django formset using clean

Tags: python, django, forms, inline-formset, formsets

How do you alter fields in each form of a Django formset using the `clean` method?

```
class MyInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['inputted'] == self.cleaned_data['answer']:
            self.cleaned_data['is_correct'] = True
        return self.cleaned_data
```

This isn't working and I've seen people iterate over each form but they only validate and not alter. If I iterate over each form how do I then return the `cleaned_data`? In other words:

```
class MyInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):    
        for form in self.forms:
            if form.cleaned_data['inputted'] == form.cleaned_data['answer']:
                form.cleaned_data['is_correct'] = True
        ...?
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on ssomnoremac comment, I used form.instance.field_i_wanted_to_change in the BaseModelFormSet clean method instead of form.cleaned_data['field_i_wanted_to_change'] and it worked. Something like

```
class MyInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

def clean(self):
    for form in self.forms:
        if form.cleaned_data['inputted'] == form.cleaned_data['answer']:
            form.instance.is_correct = True
```

In my case, I had already called clean_field_i_wanted_to_change, so the order is clean_field > clean @ MyInlineFormSet
Django 1.11

Comment: I am facing an exact similar situation. In my formset one of the fields is a boolean with default as `False`. Within the `for form in self.forms:` I am running a check and trying to **change** the boolean's status to `True` but not working. My code goes like this: `if someVar < someValue:` `if form.cleaned_data['myBool'] == False:` `form.instance.myBool = True`. Somehow I am unable to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are on the right track by iterating through each form and setting the cleaned data (your second example). BaseFormSet has a property called `cleaned_data` that returns a list of the cleaned data for each form. Is that what you want? E.g.:

```
return self.cleaned_data
```

It literally returns:

```
[form.cleaned_data for form in self.forms]
```

which should have the correct data (as modified), if I'm reading the code correctly.

If you are only interested in saving the value in your model, I suggest you avoid the `clean` method and instead override the `save` methods:

```
def save_new(self, form, commit=True):
    form.instance.is_correct = ...
    return super(...).save_new(...)

def save_existing(...)
```

Comment: David, thanks. Your answer is right about self.cleaned_data
but that still didn't change the field. The problem was cleaned_data is only an accessor not a modifier. What I needed instead:
'form.instance.is_correct = True'
form.instance actually modifies the field as explained in the docs [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-clean-on-a-modelformset]

Comment: Added to my answer. I'm glad you figured it out and I think this is a useful question, since inline forms need to be handled a bit differently than normal forms. Feel free to submit your own answer if mine doesn't say what you want.